# Mysql - Return only first row having the same unique ids

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

Consider the following table:

[image]

As shown in image, I want to return all the data from only first distinct id. How can I achieve that in MySQL ?

Comment: Nothing in your table appears to be called "id", so the question is quite unclear.  The image is also unclear.  Put the data in your question as a *text table*.

Comment: what actually have you tried and failed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with a subquery. Assuming that by *first* you mean the row with the earlier `start_time`, that would be:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.start_time = (
    select min(t1.start_time) from mytable t1 where t1.call_unique_id = t.call_unique_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from your_table t1
join
(
  select min(call_unique_id) as id
  from your_table
  group by start_time
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

`group by` should also do the job. so try

```
select * from your_table group by call_unique_id
```